# Javascript: Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The play() request was interrupted by a new load request

Tags: javascript, html

I am learning development and have an uncaught load error on a video I have as a background of a website.

The goal is to have it automatically choose between two different videos on webpage load, but I seem to be missing something in the code below, as I am getting error: : Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The play() request was interrupted by a new load request.

Can anyone help me to understand the error at hand, and how I can fix it?

HTML:

```
  <video class="my-video" id="myVideo" autoplay loop muted preload="none" playsinline>
    <source src="videolink1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
  </video>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
const video = document.getElementById("myVideo");

const videoSources = [
  'https://videolink1.mp4',
  'https://videolink2.mp4'
];

function changeVideoSourceRandomly() {
  const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * videoSources.length);
  const randomSource = videoSources[randomIndex];
  const source = video.querySelector('source');
  source.src = randomSource;
  video.load();
}

changeVideoSourceRandomly();
```

I havent been understanding the google error result, could use some help understanding how to adjust my code.

Comment: It sounds like the video is trying to play but is being *cut-off* because another video is trying to load at the same time. Please create a runnable snippet for us to debug. Look for the `<>` icon in the question editor.

Answer (score 0):

you have to pause the video before changing to a new video.

change your code to this and it should work.

```
      function changeVideoSourceRandomly() {
  const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * videoSources.length);
  const randomSource = videoSources[randomIndex];
  const source = video.querySelector('source');
  
   
  video.pause(); 
  source.src = randomSource; 
  video.load();
   
  if (!video.paused) {
    video.play();
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Mathieu, thanks for the reply. Although this changed the error, it went from a .load error to a .play error. Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The play() request was interrupted by a call to pause().

Answer (score 0):

This fixed my problems!

```
function changeVideoSourceRandomly() {
  const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * videoSources.length);
  const randomSource = videoSources[randomIndex];
  const source = video.querySelector('source');
  source.src = randomSource;
  video.load();
}

// var playPromise = video.play();
video.play().then(_ => {
    changeVideoSourceRandomly();
  })
  .catch(error => {
  console.log("Video not loaded", error)});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).